# Best mouse for a Windows Developer who uses OS X+Parallels

Tags: macos, windows, hardware, mouse, parallels-desktop

I love using Macbook Pros for my professional work and general life use.  However, by trade I'm a software engineer for all-things Windows/Microsoft based.

As such, I run my Windows VMs in Parallels in OS X.  I'm looking to go through a round of personal upgrades, and I wanted to know what is the best moderately priced mouse to use for such an environment.

This is a bit atypical to the "what is the best mouse" question.  As I'm sure many of you are aware, there are differences in how an Apple mouse can behave (think the Magic Mouse with it's dragging ability) and all of the bajillion buttons you can have on an professional mouse for Windows.

Have any of you found a really good, moderately priced mouse that seems to work well in both Windows and OS X?

Comment: Personally, I use the [MX Master](https://goo.gl/ES1g57) on my iMac with Win 10 and Win 7 VBox machines.  It is the best mouse I have ever used on either platform.    Be aware, this question may get flagged because it's opinion based, but I wanted to at least point you in a direction.

Comment: *Don't* ask the same question twice.

Comment: Is that an accidental double post or can you not wait three minutes?

Comment: Guys, please open.  I have no clue how I double-posted this.  I did copy-and-paste the details to ask about the same question for a mouse.  But I did modify 25% of it.  Also, I COMPLETELY hand-keyed the new title.  I'm not sure what happened. @allan can you reopen this?

Comment: Nevermind... I guess I accidentally typed in "Keyboard" in the title, and I missed one other reference.  This wasn't an intentional dupe.  Can I undelete my old question? :D